# sql vba query expression syntax error

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to run the following through vba sq in access but get an error "Extra ) in query expression '0)'". Following is the query expression:

```
mnthfld = "SELECT IIf([issuedate] <= #" & useDateUpper & "#," & _
    "IIf([expirydate] <= #" & useDateUpper & "#, 0, IIf([expirydate <=#" & useDateUpper & "#," & _
    "([expirydate]-#" & useDateUpper & "#+1)/([expirydate]-[effectivedate]+1),[grosspremium]),0),0) as 'EP M" & _
    Format(useDateLower, "mm yyyy") & "' FROM tblEpData"
```

> Any help is appreciated. My hunch is that I'm using brackets wrongly in the subtraction and division parts.

UPDATE:

Snapshot of the mnthfield string on one iteration:

```
IIf([issuedate] <= #11/30/2015#,IIf([expirydate] <= #11/30/2015#, 0, IIf([expirydate <=#11/30/2015#,([expirydate]-#11/30/2015#+1)/([expirydate]-[effectivedate]+1),[grosspremium]),0,0)) as [EP M11 2015]
```

Comment: immediately after you set mnthfld, use `msgbox mnthfld` to display the overall string you've concocted and post that so it's easy to detect any syntax errors...

Comment: The select and from commands are omitted from the snapshot, however that is not the cause of the error.

Comment: at least one `[expirydate]` is missing the closing `]`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `]` in statement `[expirydate <=#" & useDateUpper` and remove the `,0` from `[grosspremium]),0` should work. Final query looks like :

```
SELECT 
IIf
(
    [issuedate] <= #11/30/2015#, 
    IIf
    (
        [expirydate] <= #11/30/2015#, 
        0, 
        IIf
        (
            [expirydate] <=#11/30/2015#,
            ([expirydate]-#"11/30/2015"#+1)/([expirydate]-[effectivedate]+1),
            [grosspremium]
        )
    ),
    0
) as [EP M11 2015]
```

Comment: Still missing the closing `]` on `[expirydate]` on the final nested IIf ;)

Comment: You're right, @Dave, but it is forgetten from the question :(

Answer (score 1):

Each instance of IIf requires 3 parameters (bool_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)

I've converted the below string to be syntactically correct; you'll need to review it to make sure it's what you expected it to be doing though!

`IIf([issuedate]<= #11/30/2015#,IIf([expirydate] <= #11/30/2015#, 0, IIf([expirydate] <=#11/30/2015#,(([expirydate]-#11/30/2015#+1)/([expirydate]-[effectivedate]+1)),[grosspremium])),0) as [EP M11 2015]`